# Trie - Implementation in java

Tags: java, trie

I know there is plenty of material available regarding it but i had quite specific questions.
I have a file containing postal codes and i have to create trie data structure using those codes.
I have written my implementation which is -

```
public class Trie{

TrieNode root = null;

public void addWord(String zipCodeStr){
    if(root==null){
        root = new TrieNode();
    }
    TrieNode current = root;
    for(char c : zipCodeStr.toCharArray()){
        if(current.childern[Character.getNumericValue(c)]==null){
            current.childern[Character.getNumericValue(c)] = new TrieNode();
        }
        current = current.childern[Character.getNumericValue(c)];
    }
    current.isWord = true;
}

public boolean exists(String zipCodeStr){
    boolean result = true;
    TrieNode current = root;
    for(char c : zipCodeStr.toCharArray()){
        if(current.childern[Character.getNumericValue(c)]==null){
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        current = current.childern[Character.getNumericValue(c)];
    }
    if(result && current.isWord){
        result = true;
    }else{
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

private static class TrieNode{

    TrieNode[] childern = new TrieNode[10];
    boolean isWord = false;

    public TrieNode() {
    }

}
}
```

Here, i am not storing any value as position gives that information.

Questions - i) Can it be further improvised?
ii) Raw text file size containing 27000+ codes is around 190kb and i checked the size of trie object using a profiler it came out to be much more.
[image: Profiler output]
Are these two size related? Should trie size be less than raw text file size?

Thanks,
Ouney

Comment: Your trie node occupies 24 bytes itself plus 104 bytes for `children` array. Numbers seem to be okay. Organizing data in structures in most cases you trade space for access speed (file: less space, longer access, trie: more space, faster access).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that ~9/10 nodes are leafs (don't contain children), you can significantly decrease space that whole structure occupies by lazy initialization of `children` array:

```
private static class TrieNode {
    TrieNode[] children = null;  
    boolean isWord = false;
}
```

Now you need to create a new array only if it is actually needed:

```
public void addWord(String zipCodeStr) {
   if (root == null){
        root = new TrieNode();
   }
   TrieNode current = root;
   for (char c : zipCodeStr.toCharArray()) {
       if (current.children == null) {
           current.children = new TrieNode[10];
       }
       if (current.children[Character.getNumericValue(c)] == null) {
           current.children[Character.getNumericValue(c)] = new TrieNode();
       }
       current = current.children[Character.getNumericValue(c)];
   }
   current.isWord = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Indeed a helpful suggestion. Deepest level trie nodes refer to arrays which are not being used and greatly reduces instances of array. Thanks.

Comment: I also get that raw text file size is not related. If i have 27000 postal codes then in UTF-8 it will occupy 27000*6 = 162000 bytes (162 kb) while Trie data structure will hold much more depending on the distribution.

Comment: @Ouney this is tradeoff for better access. In Java objects cannot be less than 16 bytes, then size is increased by step of 8 bytes: 24, 32,... In your trie you need ~1.2 24-byte object for each zip code, so ~800Kb is the best you can achieve.

Comment: @Sasha..can u pls elaborate last comment about 24 bytes?

Comment: @Ouney header 8b + 1 reference 8b + 1 boolean 1b = 17bytes "rounded up" to 24. http://btoddb-java-sizing.blogspot.ru/ You can compress it to 16 bytes using `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` JVM property